# Using "temporary" variables in Double Linked Lists

Tags: java, list, sorting

I was supposed to make a Double Linked List in Java in a given exercise. Is it a good practice to use temporary variables to store values in order to sort the list ascending/descending? Is it possible to sort it ascending/descending without using these temporary/auxiliary variables? I've been trying to do it for the last couple hours but haven't succeeded.

This is how I declared my list:

```
private static class List {
  public int num;
  public List next;
  public List previous;
}
```

In my *main* method, I declared the starting and ending points:

```
List start = null;
List end = null;
List current;
```

Then, the exercise demanded that it was allowed to add numbers both at the beginning and at the end of the list. This is how I add it at the beginning of the list:

```
List newElement = new List();
newElement.num = input.nextInt();
if (start == null) {
  start = newElement;
  end = newElement;
  newElement.next = null;
  newElement.previous = null;
} else {
  newElement.next = start;
  start = newElement;
  start.next.previous = start;
}
```

And at the end of the list:

```
    newElement.num = input.nextInt();
    if (start == null) {
      start = newElement;
      end = newElement;
      newElement.next = null;
      newElement.previous = null;
    } else {
      end.next = newElement;
      end.previous = end;
      end = newElement;
      newElement.next = null;
    }
```

Finally, how I sort it ascending:

```
current = start;
int tmp = 0; //temporary variable that I do not know wether I'm supposed to use or not
while (current.next != null) {
    if (current.num > current.next.num) {
        tmp = current.next.num;
        current.next.num = current.num;
        current.num = tmp;
    }
    current = current.next;
}

current = end;
tmp = 0;
while (current.previous != null) {
    if (current.num < current.previous.num) {
        tmp = current.previous.num;
        current.previous.num = current.num;
        current.num = tmp;
    }
    current = current.previous;
}
```

Sometimes it scrambles some numbers, depending on the other, so I suppose it's not correct. To fix that, I tried checking the list both forward and reverse, as you can see in the code above, but apparently that's not the problem.

Is there a way to sort it ascending without using a temporary variable? I've already tried at least 20 times but it always lost reference to either next or previous addresses. I'm a beginner.

Comment: You may find it useful to look up algorithms for sorting lists. There's a whole bunch of them, optimized for different situations, and you may be able to adapt one of them here.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know there is a well known problem  to swap two numbers without using temporary variable.Look for that and the temporary variable will be gone.